# css анимация вызывает артефакты

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

```css
@keyframes loader-box {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.3)
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.ajax-loader {
  position: relative;
}

.ajax-loader span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(33% - 1px);
  height: calc(33% - 1px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: loader-box 1s infinite linear;
}

.ajax-loader .loader-column-1 {
  left: 0;
}

.ajax-loader .loader-column-2 {
  left: 33%;
}

.ajax-loader .loader-column-3 {
  left: 66%;
}

.ajax-loader .loader-row-1 {
  top: 0;
}

.ajax-loader .loader-row-2 {
  top: 33%;
}

.ajax-loader .loader-row-3 {
  top: 66%;
}

.ajax-loader span:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #e6261f;
}

.ajax-loader span:nth-child(2),
span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
  background-color: #eb7532;
}

.ajax-loader span:nth-child(3),
span:nth-child(5),
span:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  background-color: #f7d038;
}

.ajax-loader span:nth-child(6),
span:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
  background-color: #a3e048;
}

.ajax-loader span:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  background-color: #49da9a;
}

#big-loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#small-loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#big-row {
  font-size: 45px;
}

#small-row {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<span id="big-row">Sample text
<div class="ajax-loader" id="big-loader">
<span class="loader-column-1 loader-row-1"></span>
<span class="loader-column-2 loader-row-1"></span>
<span class="loader-column-3 loader-row-1"></span>
<span class="loader-column-1 loader-row-2"></span>
<span class="loader-column-2 loader-row-2"></span>
<span class="loader-column-3 loader-row-2"></span>
<span class="loader-column-1 loader-row-3"></span>
<span class="loader-column-2 loader-row-3"></span>
<span class="loader-column-3 loader-row-3"></span>
</div>
</span>
<br />
<span id="small-row">Sample text 2
<div class="ajax-loader" id="small-loader">
<span class="loader-column-1 loader-row-1"></span>
<span class="loader-column-2 loader-row-1"></span>
<span class="loader-column-3 loader-row-1"></span>
<span class="loader-column-1 loader-row-2"></span>
<span class="loader-column-2 loader-row-2"></span>
<span class="loader-column-3 loader-row-2"></span>
<span class="loader-column-1 loader-row-3"></span>
<span class="loader-column-2 loader-row-3"></span>
<span class="loader-column-3 loader-row-3"></span>
</div>
</span>
```

При увеличении квадратов до максимального размера появляются артефакты в виде полос на краях квадратов. При этом между квадратами ещё остается место, так что дело не в наложении их друг на друга. Как это исправить?

Comment: Что бы была понятно суть вопроса и проблемы, надо добавлять код с проблемой, не знаю как и чем ты увеличивал, но в данном варианте артефактов не видно...

Comment: Они видны прямо в этом коде
https://imgur.com/a/c67x4

Comment: Ну хоть убей не вижу ни каких проблем....   кстати прикольный пример мне понравилось...  красиво сделано...

Comment: Добавил ссылку в комментарий

Comment: да, по ссылке вижу артефакты... кстати , span эл строчный а div блочный, блочный элемент в строчный нельзя засовывать эти элементы "small-row" и "big-row" замени на div ... а как ты анимашку в gif  перевел, плагин или как?

Comment: не скажу наверняка, но это gif портит всю картину...  это проблема из-за gif

Comment: Просто записал видео с экрана.
Как gif может что-то портить, если сама анимация на css?

Comment: Такие подробности надо сразу отмечать в вопросе... что с экрана запись...  Это проблема в частоте кадров записи и частота воспроизведения анимации...   не скажу с какой частотой производиться анимация css, можешь попробовать менять частоту при записи...

Comment: При чем тут частота кадров, если проблемы с анимацией у меня видны прямо в окне просмотра сниппета?

Comment: почему тут нет этих проблем?

Comment: У меня есть в хроме на линуксе, сейчас перезагрузился в хром на винде, тут уже нет